# location.href not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used location.href in my earlier days but now its not redirecting to page. here is my code

```
function AuthenticateUserWithPage() {
var UId = $('#amwayId').val();//username
var UPw = $('#amwayPw').val();//password
var ischecked = $('#idSave').is(':checked');// check remember me checkbox status

if (UId != '' && UPw != '') {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../KPPRMobService/PNBMobWebService.asmx/IsValidUserWithPage",
        data: JSON.stringify({ username: UId, password: UPw, ischecked: ischecked }),
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = data.d;
            if (obj != "FALSE") {
                var targetUrl = "http://" + window.location.host + obj;
                window.location.href = targetUrl;
                //window.location.replace(targetUrl);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#amwayId').val('');
                //if username or password is invalid
                alert("Please check your ID or password. The ID is not registered or the ID/ password is wrong.");
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            //if error occured.
            $('#amwayId').val('');
            alert("You cannot log in. Contact support center for further inquiries..");
        }
    });

}
else {
    //if username or password is null
    alert("Please enter ID/ password.");
    return false;
}
```

}

I use this link as reference: [reference](http://javarevisited.blogspot.jp/2013/12/how-to-redirect-page-or-url-jQuery-JavaScript-Example.html).Thanks in Advance.

Comment: there's nothing obviously wrong with your `window.location.href`, the problem lays somewhere else.

Comment: What is the value of `obj`?

Comment: have you any error in your console?

Comment: Have u tried using location.assign ?

Comment: Are you sure your test reached to if (obj != "FALSE") {} block in success handler?

Comment: obj returns my page. I have tested it. I have also checked location.assign Gerald but it didn't work. I would like to know if anything is required on html side for this.

Comment: I have debug through each and every line again today but page is not redirecting to the redirectURL. Anything i am missing then please suggest.

Comment: Just an idea: `var targetUrl = "http://" + window.location.host + '/' +  obj;`

Comment: Need to put return false after the call of method instead of putting it in the ajax call. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php:

```
 $form_data = array();
 $form_data['message'] = "success";
 $form_data['redirect'] = "http://www.example.com/example";
 echo json_encode($form_data)
```

Ajax:

```
if (data.message == 'success') {
window.location.href = data.redirect;
return false;
}else if(){
etc...
}
```