# Data doesn't match result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm really sorry to ask it here, but I've tried everything to solve my problem. The thing is I'm giving a *delete_id* trough *AJAX* to my *PHP script*. In that *PHP script* I control if *the delete_id* exist.

Now the strange thing is, that I *alert* the delete_id and it says *75*. 75 exist(I printed the query in PHPmyAdmin manualy and there it worked) but it won't delete it as planned.

**My AJAX part:**

```
$('.btn.btn-xs.btn-danger').click(function(){
    var delete_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var delete_id_url = 'action=deleting&id='+delete_id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "/panel/includes/handlers/404.handler.php",
            data: delete_id_url,
            success: function responseText(response)
                {
                  $.parseJSON(response);

                    if(response.indexOf(1) > -1)
                    {
                        alert('Er is helaas geen overeenkomst in onze database gekomen.');
                        alert(delete_id);
                    }
                    else if(response.indexOf(2) > -1)
                    {
                        alert('Het opgegeven ID nummer is helaas geen geldig getal.');
                    }
                    else if(response.IndexOf(100) > -1)
                    {
                        alert('De opgegeven rij is verwijderd.');
                        $(delete_id).hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('or nah');
                    }
                }
    });
});
```

**My PHP part:**

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'deleting')
    {
        $intDelete = trim($_POST['id']);
        $errors    = array();

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM error WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $intDelete);
            $stmt->execute();
            $intSelect = $stmt->num_rows();
            $stmt->close();

                // Controle part.
                if($intSelect == 0)
                {
                    $errors[] = 1;
                    $bolean   = true;
                }
                if(!ctype_digit($intDelete))
                {
                    $errors[] = 2;
                    $bolean   = true;
                }

                    if($bolean == false)
                    {
                        $errors[] = 100;

                            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM error WHERE id = ?");
                            $stmt->bind_param('i', $intDelete);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->close();
                    }
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($errors);
    }
```

So the result I'm getting from the PHP part is $errors[] = '1';. Thank you for helping in advance! English isn't BTW my mother tongue, so it is quite difficult to describe my problem.

Comment: I do like this and works perfectly
[stackoverlflow-link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740751/location-href-not-working/25741981#25741981

Comment: @Perlica I've tried making something like this earlier, it was messier and a lot harder...

Comment: Because you never set your variable $bolean to false, it will be true for your last if statement and your DELETE statement will not be executed.

Comment: @VMai I've changed it, but now it will delete the row, but still give the first error. It will keep giving me $errors[] = '1' in return

Comment: You should call `$stmt->store_result();` before `$intSelect = $stmt->num_rows();` to get the number of rows.