# AJAX cannot read echo data from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, echo

I've been testing my register, and to an extent the code works. But it seems to not be able to compare the text from the PHP script.

I tried using existing email AND username, existing email, existing username and two non-existing username and email. But all give me the echoed data + Fail (which is the end conditional statement in JQuery).

**JQuery:**

```
$( function ajaxRegCheck() {
    $('#reg_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'save_register.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data)
            {

                if(data == "un_em_exists"){
                    alert(data+" Username and Email exists.");
                } else if(data == "un_exists") {
                    alert(data+" Username exists.");
                } else if(data == "em_exists") {
                    alert(data+" Email exists.");
                } else if(data == "success"){
                    alert(data+" Created account.");
                } else {
                    alert(data+ " Fail.");
                }
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP Register:**

```
if(($exist_check_user->rowCount() > 0) AND ($exist_check_em->rowCount() > 0)){
    echo "un_em_exists";
} else if($exist_check_user->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo "un_exists";
} else if($exist_check_em->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo "em_exists";
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (username, email, password) VALUES (:r_un, :r_em, :r_pw)";
    $q = $cdb->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':r_un'=>$reg_username,':r_em'=>$reg_email,':r_pw'=>$reg_pw));
    echo "success";
}
```

I do not why it skips the if statements in the JQuery and go straight to the last else condition. It clearly outputs the string from the PHP side correctly, but it doesn't seem to be able to compare the string?

For example, if I register with existing username and email, it'll echo 'un_em_exists' response. On the JQuery the alert matches this as it says, "un_em_exists Fail.", which is the last statement.

**UPDATE:**

Found the problem, but not too sure how to fix. I tested the string length, and in return I get string length 16 (testing from the JQuery side), and on PHP I get 12 - which is the correct amount for "un_em_exists".

I do not know what the extra 4 amounts come from though.

Comment: Have you checked string length? There i.e. might be extra new lines or other whitespaces.

Comment: It would be easier to send a code in PHP and convert and get its string value client side.

Comment: Check the data type of `data` which is being returned during your Ajax call, you may be getting an object back rather than a String, which would cause all of your String comparisons to be false.

Comment: Can confirm. Data type is String. I used: alert(jQuery.type(data)+ " Fail.");

Comment: Use json_encode something like this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740751/location-href-not-working/25741981#25741981

Comment: @Perlica Why would json_encode work over what I'm doing? It is string type, and the comparison is also a string. Logically it should compare the two :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After success trim your data by using data.trim(), might be there is whitespace

Comment: Thanks! I did not think this would be the answer since from the naked eye it looks equal. But after I have tested both string lengths, I realised there's a problem as it yielded 16 instead of 12 characters. I do not know where the extra 4 characters come from though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the returned value is text like so:

```
$( function ajaxRegCheck() {
    $('#reg_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'text',
            type: "POST",
            url: 'save_register.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data)
            {

                if(data == "un_em_exists"){
                    alert(data+" Username and Email exists.");
                } else if(data == "un_exists") {
                    alert(data+" Username exists.");
                } else if(data == "em_exists") {
                    alert(data+" Email exists.");
                } else if(data == "success"){
                    alert(data+" Created account.");
                } else {
                    alert(data+ " Fail.");
                }
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just added this and with the below comment on exit; still same behaviour.